# Create a new div with text from textarea above it when user clicks 'submit' - javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am asking if someone can give me a simple javascript code that will place the text written by a user in a textarea into a new div created when the user clicks on submit button.

Here is the form:

```
       <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="profile.php" method="post" target="hidden-form" >

Write text here: 
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="comment here" rows="1" cols="40" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" "/>
</form>
<IFRAME style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></IFRAME>
```

Comment: are u using jquery? try jquery.append

Comment: I am not used to javascript or jquery. that's why i asked for a simple code.

Comment: Where are you going to store the comment data?

Comment: Already taken care of by the Iframe. it is taking the data to the database without reloading the page. do you have the code I need please?

Comment: iframe to take form data to database? You should really look into jQuery and proper AJAX functions buddy.

Comment: Add the complete code here, so it will be easy to give a proper answer. I have no idea how to answer this right now.

Comment: I am sure of what I am saying. I have seen data changing in database but not in the page. that's why I am asking for a simple javascript that will do this. If you can sketch one, please do that for me.

Comment: the comment is supposed to go into the text area, and when the user clicks submit button, I want javascript to create new div below it with the content of the textarea. got it now?

Comment: please have a look my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function updateDiv()
    {
        var x = $('#comment').val();
        $( "#UserCommentsDiv" ).append("<div>" + x + "</div>");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="profile.php" method="post" target="hidden-form" >
        Write text here: 
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="comment here" rows="1" cols="40" ></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="updateDiv();"/>
    </form>

    <div id="UserCommentsDiv"></div>
    <IFRAME style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></IFRAME> 
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7hR76/1)

Comment: it works well without the form, but with the form, it creates the div and removes it immediately. why is that?

Comment: have you seen the behavior? what might it be?

Comment: I updated the code, so check the demo again, I added your form tags, its working fine

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot for this. It is the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with something like this in profile.php

```
<?php 

$comment = $_POST['comment'];

?>
```

Then add this in your div where you want.

```
<?php echo $comment; ?>
```

Comment: let me try this. hope it will work without reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure javaScript solution

**HTML**

```
<form >
<div id="container">
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="comment here" rows="1" cols="40" ></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="storeData()"/>
</div>

</form>
```

**javaScript**

```
function storeData(){
    var commentTag = document.getElementById('comment');

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "result";
    newDiv.innerHTML = commentTag.value;

    var submitTag = document.getElementById('submit');
    parDiv = document.getElementById('container');
    container.insertBefore(newDiv, submitTag);
}
```

**UPDATE**

When use in `form` your input type should be `button` instead of `submit`

Shuld be

```
<input type="button"
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYe6J/3/)

Comment: thanks Suman. how do i initialize the function when the user clicks on submit?

Comment: You can see the `inline` initalize the `storeData()` at input on above answer. but you can do this way as well, `document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', storeData);`

Comment: Thanks alot Suman. It works perfectly. I love your approach. Thanks again

Comment: when I add the <form></form tags, it blinks the new div then disappears. why is that?

Comment: Please have a look udpated answer.

Comment: if I change that, the database is not updated with the php code of if(isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: how your form is being submited, is it by jquery or traditional way?

Comment: you basically want the submit form and at the same time without page refresh the comment should be display into div, I think in this case ajax is more suitable.

Comment: now that kills my nerves. is there some ready baked ajax code?

Comment: It's gives you some direction about ajax http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php

Comment: thanks for spending time for me. I'm going to learn that slowly and I'll tell you if I succeed.